# Grails criteria sort and paginate

Tags: sorting, grails, pagination, grails-orm, criteria

I am trying something like this:

```
    def pagingParams = SortingAndPagingUtils.preparePaging(params)

    def Objs = Obj.createCriteria().list(pagingParams) {
        baseCriteria(params, delegate)
    }
```

Where my pagingParams look like:

```
    [max: pageSize, offset: offset]
```

and my `baseCriteria` creates an order like:

```
    [['field','ASC]]
```

Assume my page size is 10. I am first fetching 10 results - they are indeed sorted OK by `field`. I fetch another 10 (second page). In themselves, the second page results are sorted just fine, however, they are not sorted based on the first page results.

Simple example:

`First page: [10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]`

`Second page: [9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ...]`

How can I fix this? Is it normal or am I missing something?

**later edit:**

I observed that if I increase the page size, then I don't get such unsorted results (kinda obvious, but worth mentioning)

**even later edit:**

I apologise for not making this clear earlier. Here is how the `baseCriteria` method looks like:

```
private def baseCriteria(params, builder) {
    def sortOrderPairs = SortingAndPagingUtils.prepareSorting(params)
    def result = {
        sortOrderPairs.each {
            order((it[0] as String), (it[1] as String))
        }
    }
    result.delegate = builder
    result()
}
```

Where `sortOrderPairs` looks like

```
    [['field','ASC]]
```

Now to my knowledge, this

```
        sortOrderPairs.each {
            order((it[0] as String), (it[1] as String))
        }
```

should do the trick, am I right? Yet it does not.

**even lateeer edit**

I tried simplifying everything and having only

```
    def tasks = Obj.createCriteria().list(max: pageSize, offset: pageSize * (currentPage - 1)) {
        order('field', 'DESC')
    }
```

But still, problem persists!

even tried

```
    def tasks = Task.createCriteria().list(max: pageSize, offset: pageSize * (currentPage - 1), sort: 'field', order: 'DESC');
```

Same problem

Comment: What is SortingAndPagingUtils? I have yet to find anything on it?

Comment: It is just a utility class I created, nothing more

Answer (score 2):

baseCriteria is returning a list of list and records actually never got sorted as there is no order specified, it's the records which seems ordered to you which is random actually or may be it's just showing it. To test that replace,

```
     baseCriteria(params, delegate)
```

with some DRY code. For example,

```
 order("name","asc")
```

Here, name is hard coded for DRY run.Below are example DRY criteria and it worked perfectly and orders didn't get disrupted. Try

```
   def Objs = Group.createCriteria().list([max:10,offset:0]) {
        order("name","asc")
    }
```

and then

```
 def Objs = Group.createCriteria().list([max:10,offset:10]) {
        order("name","asc")
 }
```

and so on and observe the outputs. If it works, correct the method calls to set correct params and order field and order.